# Night Light starts earlier than scheduled/set time

Tags: release-hera, nightlight

The nightlight appears to start earlier than the scheduled time. I set it to start at 2AM and end at 5AM but it started about 15 minutes earlier than 2AM. I am using elementaryOS 5.1 Hera. Also experiencing an occasional flicker just like this: [Juno: Night light flickering](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/19343/juno-night-light-flickering)[image: nightlight manual set time]

Any ideas on how to fix either of the issues/bugs?